# Is this case possible (hedgehog metric, colinearity)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My topology class was asked to prove that the hedgehog metric was indeed a metric (the details are irrelevant for my question). This does not concern the proof itself, but rather the structure of the proof.

To make a long story short, while proving the triangle inequality for the hedgehog metric, cases like the following were deemed impossible by many (including the professor) and were not considered in the proof for that reason.

Let X, Y, Z be points on a real 2d plane.

a.) X, Y, and (0,0) lie on the same line.

b.) X, Z, and (0,0) lie on the same line.

c.) Y, Z, and (0,0) do not lie on the same line.

This was deemed impossible because if X, Y, and (0,0) were all in one line, and X, Z, and (0,0) were all in one line, then "transitively," Y, Z and (0,0) must lie on the same line.

However, I assert that this is not impossible, it merely implies that X = (0,0). So, in my proof, I considered cases like this.

What do you think?

Comment: Maybe the professor at some point supposed that $X,Y,Z$ are points not equal to $(0,0)$? In the event that $X$ is equal to zero, it's clear that the triangle equality would hold, so I suppose that is a situation that can be approached separately.

Comment: There is no restriction on what X, Y, and Z are. The case was simply deemed geometrically impossible.

Comment: If we take $X,Y,Z$ and $(0,0)$ to be arbitrary, not necessarily distinct, point in $\mathbb R^2$ then you definitely seem to be in the right. However, from the context, it seems like there was some sort of miscommunication. Also, I believe your name is spelled with two p's :)